# Call an Object from another file

Tags: dart, flutter

I have some code in main.dart file below. It will `push` to `new Show()` in `show.dart` file.

main.dart

```
import 'show.dart';
//.... 
Navigator.of(context).pop();
Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (BuildContext context) => new Show()));
//...
 Future<void> _getSomething() async {
  }
//...
```

and the button I create on show.dart

```
                        //...                         
                        IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.menu,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 28,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () => print("back to main.dart and call _getSomething()"),
                          ),
```

Now, How can I back to `main.dart` and call `_getSomething()` from `show.dart` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a parameter (e.g., a `bool`) in the onPressed call that would then decide whether or not `_getSomething()` should be run when you're navigating to `main.dart`.

This [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31) has a section called **Give me some data back, man** describing how to pass a value to the prior screen. Another benefit is that you're not adding additional pages to the stack if you chose to use `Navigator.push()` causing a weird flow when the user hits the back button.